# How To Enable CSP Apache/debian

Tags: apache, configuration, web-development-server

I am A Front-end guy and need the help of a backend developer. I need to Fix the content security policies for a page I'm working on. I am just unsure of the syntax. I need to declare that script from self and the third party cdn's that I'm using are ok to load
also the styles. I've looked everywhere and can't find anything that makes a clear picture this is what I,m trying.

```
    Header set Content-Secruity-Policy style-src 'self' code.ionicframework.com
```

The error from apachectl configtest is header set has too many arguments. Can someone please explain what I'm doing?

Comment: `...Secruity...`? Probably doesn't do what you intend it to do...

Answer (score 0):

Please adjust your configuration by using double quotes "

```
Header set Content-Secruity-Policy "style-src 'self' code.ionicframework.com"
```

Then check for the syntax with `apachectl configtest` and finally `reload | restart` the apache service.

```
$ curl -IL http://domain-or-IP
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 05 Oct 2021 21:12:47 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
Last-Modified: Tue, 05 Oct 2021 21:09:29 GMT
ETag: "29cd-5cda171fef842"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 10701
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Secruity-Policy: style-src 'self' code.ionicframework.com   <- HERE!
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: Thanks, Reynaldo I Know it's just a syntax problem But I Was Lost Bad.